# React npm run build error in node modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build, typeerror

I created a react app locally doing `npx create-react-app appname`, removed the stock files that came with it did `npm start` saw my changed locally and then did an `npm run build` and I got this error:

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
^
TypeError: MiniCssExtractPlugin is not a constructor
```

Does anyone know what to do in this scenario?

Answer (score -1):

mini-css-extract-plugin requires webpack >= 4.1.0

ref: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/3

Comment: It says my webpack is: webpack@5.66.0